# Memory error solutions in Python

Tags: python, memory-management

I'm loading a lot of objects with dicts containing large string values. Overall, the program exceeds 2GB and crashes. It doesn't exceed by much, but I could well have even larger data later.

It seems Python 32bit is unable to access more memory. I suppose for the future I need some object database system which is able to handle large data and still not be too slow (i.e. store in DB or harddrive, but keep some in memory for speed). For performance I don't want to keep the data in MySQL only but rather have some transparent mechanism which keeps as much as possible in memory.

Can you think of a good way to deal with so much data in objects?

Comment: By far the best initial solution is to run on a 64-bit machine.

Comment: Do you really need to store that many data in the ram?

Comment: Even 64bit might be only a temporary solution. Maybe someday the object number will be 8-fold. I'm basically doing network analysis on object and for speed I need most of them in memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on how complex is your data structure, take a look at these:

### [memcached](http://memcached.org/)

Key-value store, damn fast ('O(1) everything'), scales to many machines, intended for caching (not persistent). There are solutions to persist and load the data, and even [memcachedb](http://memcachedb.org/).

### [mongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/)

JSON store, can have indexes other than primary key, scales to many machines, has auto-sharding and auto-failover, persistent. Supports very fast inserts, atomic ops, a sort of built-in map-reduce for complex queries.

### [redis](http://redis.io/topics/introduction)

Key-value store, values can be structured. Has many advanced operations, atomic ops, pub/sub, master-slave replication. Operates entirely in RAM but has limited persistence mechanisms.

Consider re-formulating your question's title, something like "What in-memory database to choose" would be more informative.

Comment: Is it in-memory only? Because if it doesn't outsource parts of the network, then it wouldn't solve my memory problem.

Comment: All of these can work on multiple machines, with various degrees of transparency. E.g. one of the textbook configuration for MongoDB is a sharded redundant cluster :) Of course, you can start with just one machine. And, of course, it better use a 64-bit OS.

Comment: I think I don't understand completely :-/ Can it store some objects in memory? Will integrate more or less transparently with Python object (or do I have to rewrite all data code)?

Comment: I can't speak for MongoDB of redis, but `memcached` is a way to keep the bulk of your data on disk while caching the most frequently used parts in RAM.  If your data can be reasonably coerced into a database, do that, but memcached is the general-purpose solution.

Comment: Did I understand correctly, that besides memcached, I still would need to implement the persistent harddrive part? Most of my data a dicts for each object (containing long strings).

Answer (score 1):

You do not mention under which OS you work. AFAICT under Linux this problem doesn't exist, so I suppose you mean Windows.

I once had this problem and solved it with this method:

> I just added some RAM to my PC @ work and now wanted Python to be
>   capable to make use of it.
>
> My boot.ini has been containing the /3GB switch for quite a while, but
>   nevertheless I only could allocate 2 GB in Python.
>
> So I changed python.exe with the imagecfg.exe which I obtained from
>   http://blog.schose.net/index.php/archives/207 and it works now.
>
> This is just FYI, for the case one of you would like to be able to do
>   so as well.
>
> But be aware that it is not impossible that there are side effects.

Comment: Sounds interesting :) Maybe it can help for my particular problem now... Thx.

Comment: This will help you get past 2Gb of RAM, but it still won't help you if you want to load more data than will fit in your machine's physical memory. See @9000 's answer for ways to scale further.

Comment: True. Still might be a solution for my urgent problem now :) Thanks for the explanation! I think I can work the mentioned DBs.